# SQL - How to return a list of data

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have this SQL method below, it is suppose to return multiple rows of data, but it is only returning one item every time I try to display the data.

How do I fix that?

```
//Constant
    public static final String COL_4 = "LikeSong";
    

//Database Table
    @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE UserInfo(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Users_Name TEXT, PlaylistName TEXT,likeAlbum TEXT,LikeSong TEXT)");
        }

public String[] getLikedSongs() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] LikeSong = null;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(" SELECT " + COL_4 + " FROM " + Table_Name + " WHERE " + COL_4 + " IS NOT NULL", null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String note = cursor.getString(0);
            LikeSong = note.split(",");
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return LikeSong;
    }
```

Comment: Try ```while (cursor.next())```

Comment: that produced an error. I can only use "cursor.moveToNext()" or "cursor.moveToFirst()

Comment: LikeSong is overridden on any iteration, so as result you will always get data from last iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `while` loop in each iteration you change the value of `LikeSong`, so when the loop ends, `LikeSong` has the last value assigned to it.
I think that you want a list of arrays returned by your method `getLikedSongs()` like this:

```
public List<String[]> getLikedSongs() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(" SELECT " + COL_4 + " FROM " + Table_Name + " WHERE " + COL_4 + " IS NOT NULL", null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String note = cursor.getString(0);
            LikeSong.add(note.split(","));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return LikeSong;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Thant's the answer right here! :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay...now I see. You are reassigning  `LikeSong` for each iteration of the while loop and returning the String array after the while loop has completed. So obviously, you will get value of only the last row.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful! :)